# Concurrent modification in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've got a problem with removing items from `List` in `RecyclerView`. It contains list of checked items. I want to uncheck one item of the list.

So, method `removeGroupItem()` removes item from list of checked items. Here it is:

```
private void removeGroupItem(String groupId) {
    for (String group : pickedGroups) {
        if (group.equals(groupId))
            pickedGroups.remove(group);
    }
}
```

If I tap very fast 2-3 times on some item - it crashes. 
Here is stacktrace:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
        at com.camness.vidimguploadjun2016.trips.group_adapter.GroupsAdapter.removeGroupItem(GroupsAdapter.java:76)
        at com.camness.vidimguploadjun2016.trips.group_adapter.GroupsAdapter.access$300(GroupsAdapter.java:16)
        at com.camness.vidimguploadjun2016.trips.group_adapter.GroupsAdapter$GroupViewHolder.lambda$new$0$GroupsAdapter$GroupViewHolder(GroupsAdapter.java:65)
        at com.camness.vidimguploadjun2016.trips.group_adapter.GroupsAdapter$GroupViewHolder$$Lambda$0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6303)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:134)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24828)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6798)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Thank you all in advance for any help.

Comment: Yes, you can't remove from an ordinary collection while iterating over it like that. You'll need to iterate with an Iterator and use its remove() method.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen thank you, it solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

First of all change the logic of work. For example you can break after remove

```
    for (String group : pickedGroups) {
        if (group.equals(groupId)) {
            pickedGroups.remove(group);
            break;
        }
    }
```

But you also have to synchronize the threads which have access to this array. For example

```
    synchronized(pickedGroups) {
       for (String group : pickedGroups) {
           if (group.equals(groupId)) {
               pickedGroups.remove(group);
               break;
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: if you break it, the for loop won't work after because you exit it. which means, only first one gets removed.